# moore's law and quadratic algorithm

Tags: algorithms

I was going thru a video (from `coursera - by sedgewick`) in which he argues that `you cannot sustain Moore's law using a quadratic algorithm`.He elaborates like this

In year 197* you build a computer of power X ,and need to count N objects.This takes M days

According to `Moore's law`,you have a computer of power 2X after 1.5 years.But now you have 2N objects to count.

If you use a quadratic algorithm,

In year 197*+1.5 ,it takes (4M)/2 = 2M days

4M because the algorithm is quadratic,and division by 2 because of doubling computer power.

I find this hard to understand.I tried to work thru this as below

```
To count N objects using comp=X , it takes M days.
-> N/X = M

After 1.5 yrs ,you need to count 2N objects using comp=2X
-> 2N/(2X) -> N/X -> M days
```

where do I go wrong? can someone please help me understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `T(N)` the time (in days) needed to execute an algorithm for N objects on a computer of "power 1", then the number of days needed is first

```
T(N)/X
```

and second

```
T(2N)/2X
```

Now set T(N)=N in your first case and T(2N)=4N in your second case, and I think you can do the remaining math by yourself.

Honestly, "counting of objects" is not a really good example, because it gives the notion of a running time of O(N). Perhaps you had seen your error more easily if you had replaced "counting" by "sorting".

Answer (score 2):

When Sedgwick talks of a "quadratic" algorithm, he means one where the effort is *not* proportional to the size of the input. For instance, if you have ten letters in your alphabet, there are 100 possible two-letter words, but if you have twenty letters, it's 400 possible words, not just 200. In other words, the algorithm does something more than just "do something with every object" - usually, "do something to every combination of k objects". Therefore, if you assume that input size grows proportionally with time, and your algorithm is super-linear (e.g. quadratic) then a simple growth of computing power in proportion with time is not sufficient to keep up with the problem growth.

I should note that this is an oversimplification of both sides of the problem. There is no general rule that input size of real-world problems grows in proportion with time - very often it will grow much slower or much faster (although usually not for very long). And Moore's law is not a law but just an empirical observation, and it wasn't about CPU speeds but about the number of transistor components per chip, which has little to do with them. In fact, for quite some time the mainstream CPUs have not increased their clock speeds the way they did in the 90s, although the transistor count keeps rising. So all this is a very high-level abstract view of the question. In practice, you almost always need to look more closely at your problem to decide whether it will remain feasible or not.